How to call program while debugging in CLP program
I have this CLP:
PGM
/* 1st command */
CRTCBLPGM PGM(QTEMP/TESTPGM) +
          SRCFILE(MYSRC/QLBLSRC) +
          OPTION(*SRCDBG)
/* 2nd command */
STRISDB PGM(QTEMP/TESTPGM) +
        INVPGM(*NO) +               
        SRCF(MYSRC/QLBLSRC)
/* 3rd command to trigger the TESTPGM */
CALL PGM(BMANMTHRD) +                                
     PARM('TESTPGM' X'000000001F' 'P' X'001F')       
ENDPGM                                               

1st and 2nd commands will be executed successfully. But after the 2nd command, it will go to Request level: 3 and the 3rd command won't get executed unless I press F3 to go back to Request level: 1. How will I get the 3rd command to be executed without needing to press F3?

Put INVPGM(*CMD) instead of INVPGM(*SRC) and add the CMD parameter with the command you want to use.
STRISDB PGM(QTEMP/TESTPGM) +
        INVPGM(*CMD) +               
        CMD(CALL PGM(BMANMTHRD) +
            PARM('TESTPGM' X'000000001F' 'P' X'001F')) +
        SRCF(MYSRC/QLBLSRC)

